# How to detect if change in column values in Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to find if any value in a column going less then the permissible limit? 
For example: 
I have a column A   Which have variable data when making any changes effects values in column B.

I want to set the constraint such that if column A making any values in Column B less than 7 (by increasing or decreasing value in column A ) then that value in column A will be rejected and Column A value will not update further (Increase or Decrease). and the last value will be set as final.

so the concept here is to loop through each Row in Column A and try to increase or decrease value until condition is satisfied.

Note: values in column A must be positive

Example 1:

[Please follow this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGGuE.jpg)
 a sample excel sheet is attached below.

I just want a way to adjust values in column A so that column B values be in the permissible limit. ( ie. not below 7 ). This can be achieved by changing values in column A and then checking all rows of Column B for permissible limit, to achieve this I need to loop through each row in column B every time value is changed , which can take more processing time (Slowing down Vba). I need to achieve this without looping.

TIA

Comment: A sample excel file from Google Drive : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kHDh74X1b6Vng0d282WVRWOXc/view

Comment: Why not use "Data Validation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a sheet based event like below to capture changes happening in column A. Right click on the sheet tab where you want to do this and paste below code. *Test this on a backup.*

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, rngLast As Range
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Set rngLast = Cells.Find("*", [A1], xlFormulas, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rng In Range("B2:B" & rngLast.Row) '\\ Adjust Start Row of Column B
            If rng.Value < 7 Then
                MsgBox "Value going below specified limit!", vbExclamation
                Application.Undo
            End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, how can i use it in a module?

Comment: @Hola No you cannot if you mean a general module as the event is triggered by particular sheet component.

Comment: Is there any other solution possible?

Comment: Can you describe the difficulty you are facing if this code remains in the sheet module. Other than this, you can run VBA Macro.

Comment: Target.Offset(0, 1).Value < 7 is checking only one cell in column, I want it to check the entire column at once, because one change in Column A affecting all column B values.

Comment: OK. I have edited the code. Please test it on a backup. It will monitor complete column B whenever there's a change in Column A.